# How do I make custom radial mouse menus in Left 4 Dead?

Tags: left-4-dead

I have read online and seen screenshots of people that have created their own custom radial mouse menus to execute all kinds of different commands.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

I could post an elaborate answer which would be basically ripping off other people's work, but instead I'll just show you a link to a great tutorial. [Adding a radial menu](http://www.gamebanana.com/tuts/7509).

If you need to know what commands to use et cetera just let me know what you want to do and I (or someone else here) will help you further.

[image: An example radial menu]

Comment: At least add a quote containing the most important bit(s), in case that page ever goes down.